# Add Spree to rails app with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, spree

I'm new at RoR but I'm loving every bit of it :)

I have a small app that uses devise for authentication and it's working fine.

Now I want to add a ecommerce part nad I decided for spree. I installed spree and during installation it asked me if I wanted to use the default authentication, I said 'no'. Then it asked me for the user model which I stated 'User'.

Now I enter my app, I login it goes to the products page on spree. That's ok, but when I try to access the admin part, I get redirected to the products page.

My doubts are:
- Should I install anyway the spree_auth_devise gem?
- Should this be a problem with the database and the users role? Because on the "spree_users" table I don't have anything, only on the Users table...

How can I associate one of my existing users to an admin user on spree?

Should this be the problem or I'm missing something else?

Answer (score 4):

Did you run this:

```sh
rails g spree:custom_user User
```

http://guides.spreecommerce.com/authentication.html in the Initial Setup block

To check is user is admin:

```rb
user = User.find_by_email("master@example.com")
user.spree_roles << Spree::Role.find_or_create_by_name("admin")
## To test that this has worked, use the has_spree_role? method, like this:
user.has_spree_role?("admin")
```

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I was looking for :) Let me work on it and then I'll update this Q to let you know if it worked!

Comment: Hi @Ryan, when I saw Damienbrz reply yesterday at 2am... I was not able to try it, only to give it a quick look. I will do it today in the afternoon and then I post my results here!

Comment: I had the problem described above when trying to install spree on top of a rails app running refinery.  I can confirm that running "rails g spree:custom_user Refinery::User" fixed the problem for me.